# orthogonal complement and characteristic polynomial, demonstrations. That's right?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A and B be square matrices of the same order. Test if the characteristic polynomial of AB is the product of the characteristic polynomials of A and B respectively.

Solution:

If $A\in M_{n \times n} $ we have that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of degree $n.$
The same for $B $ and $AB.$  But we have that the degree of the polynomial of $A$ by that of $B$ is $2n.$
Therefore the statement is false.

b) Let $U$ and $V$ be vector subspaces of the Euclidean space (or unit, interchangeably) of finite dimension $W,$ such that $ W = U⊕V.$
Show whether it is true or false that $V$ is the orthogonal complement of $U.$

Considering that $W = R^2 $ with the usual scalar product and the subspaces $U = <(1,0)> $ and $V = <(1,1)>$. How is it demonstrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $<(1,0)>\bigoplus<(1,1)>\neq \mathbb{R}^2$, because this does not include $<(0,1)>$: $$a(1,0) + b(1,1) \neq c(0,1).$$ Since $W = U\bigoplus V$, we must have that $$b_{U}\bigoplus b_{V} = b_{W},$$ where $b_{U}$, $b_{V}$ and $b_{W}$ are bases of $U$, $V$ and $W$, respectively. A basis of a Euclidean vector space consists of orthogonal vectors, therefore $b_U\perp b_V \implies U\perp V$.

From $W = U\bigoplus V$ we must also have that $$\text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(V) = \text{dim}(W).$$ Hence, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and span $W$, which makes them orthogonal complements.

As for $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V=<(0,1)>$ would be the orthogonal complement to $U=<(1,0)>$, since $U\perp V$ and $\text{dim}(U)+\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(W)$.

Comment: the statement is false?

Comment: It is true, just your examples of $U$ and $V$ do not satisfy $U\bigoplus V=W$.